# SQL Server 2016 - Concatenated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table `Hashtags` with columns:

```
id, hashtag, count
```

In my stored procedure, I received a string like this:

```
#stack, #overflow, #test
```

I have to check if some of the hashtags exists and update the count, otherwise just insert a new row for each hashtag in the string.

I was trying to use IN but dont work for INSERTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the new string_split and use a MERGE statement:

```
 DECLARE @input VARCHAR(260) = '#stack,#overflow,#test'

 MERGE hashtags h 
 USING (SELECT value FROM string_split(@input, ',')) t
 ON h.hashtag = t.value 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET count = count + 1 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (hashtag, count)
     VALUES (t.value, 1);
```